# How to stop waiting for a keypress in a separate thread module in keyboard + PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, keyboard

I'm writing a PyQt5 GUI program to control drones and I need to track keystrokes. I keep track of them in a separate thread created with QThread. When I press the button for the first time, the keystroke tracking should start, but the second time I press the button, the flow should stop and the keystroke tracking too. Here is my code:

```
class Keybord_Recognition(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Keybord_Recognition, self).__init__()

    def key_recog(self, k):
        if k.event_type == 'down':
            if k.name == 'w':
                print('forward')

            elif k.name == 's':
                print('back')

            elif k.name == 'a':
                print('left')

            elif k.name == 'd':
                print('right')

            elif k.name == 'z':
                print('up')

            elif k.name == 'x':
                print('down')

    def run(self):
        keyboard.hook(self.key_recog)
        keyboard.wait('p')

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.control_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.control_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 60, 160, 150))
        self.control_btn.setObjectName("control_btn")
        self.control_btn.setCheckable(True)
        self.control_btn.clicked.connect(self.kboard_recognition)
        self.control_btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color: #aae053;\n"
                                   "border-radius: 60%;\nbackground-image: url('images/pult.png');\n"
                                   "background-repeat: no-repeat;\nbackground-position: center;}\n"
                                   "QPushButton:hover{background-color: #81eb3b;}")

    def kboard_recognition(self):
        if self.control_btn.isChecked():
            self.control_btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color: red;\n"
                                       "border-radius: 60%;\nbackground-image: url('images/pause.png');\n"
                                       "background-repeat: no-repeat;\nbackground-position: center;}\n")
            self.thread_kboard = QtCore.QThread()
            self.k_recog = Keybord_Recognition()

            self.k_recog.moveToThread(self.thread_kboard)
            self.thread_kboard.started.connect(self.k_recog.run)
            self.thread_kboard.start()

        else:
            self.control_btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color: #aae053;\n"
                                       "border-radius: 60%;\nbackground-image: url('images/pult.png');\n"
                                       "background-repeat: no-repeat;\nbackground-position: center;}\n"
                                       "QPushButton:hover{background-color: #81eb3b;}")

            keyboard.send('q')
            self.thread_kboard.terminate()
```

But when I press the button a second time, the keyboard doesn't stop tracking. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to use threads to use keyboard together with Qt, on the other hand you have to remove the callback so that the events are no longer parsed.

```py
import keyboard

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class QKeyBoard:
    def _hook_callback(self, k):
        if k.event_type == "down":
            if k.name == "w":
                print("forward")

            elif k.name == "s":
                print("back")

            elif k.name == "a":
                print("left")

            elif k.name == "d":
                print("right")

            elif k.name == "z":
                print("up")

            elif k.name == "x":
                print("down")

    def start(self):
        keyboard.hook(self._hook_callback)

    def stop(self):
        keyboard.unhook(self._hook_callback)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.control_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.control_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 60, 160, 150))
        self.control_btn.setObjectName("control_btn")
        self.control_btn.setCheckable(True)
        self.control_btn.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton{\n"
            "background-color: #aae053;\n"
            "border-radius: 60%;\n"
            "background-image: url('images/pult.png');\n"
            "background-repeat: no-repeat;\n"
            "background-position: center;}\n"
            "QPushButton:hover{\n"
            "background-color: #81eb3b;\n"
            "}"
            "QPushButton:checked{\n"
            "background-color: red;\n"
            "border-radius: 60%;\n"
            "background-image: url('images/pause.png');\n"
            "background-repeat: no-repeat;\n"
            "background-position: center;\n"
            "}"
        )


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.qkeyboard = QKeyBoard()
        self.control_btn.toggled.connect(self.handle_toggled)

    def handle_toggled(self, state):
        if state:
            self.qkeyboard.start()
        else:
            self.qkeyboard.stop()


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```